# Knitting plots to word, sizing of plots is squashed

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to create 4 bar plots that simply present number of responses split by various demographics.

Thus I have the following chunk of code

```
{r, echo = FALSE, fig.height=20, fig.width=40}  <-this is has the proper start but stackoverflow wont let me post it

a <- ggplot(data=Data, aes(x=Gender, fill=Gender))+
  geom_bar(stat="count")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = wrap_format(10))+
  ylab("Number of respondents")
b <- ggplot(data=Data, aes(x=Condition, fill=Condition))+
  geom_bar(stat="count")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = wrap_format(10))+
  ylab("Number of respondents")+
  xlab("Employment type")
c <- ggplot(data=Data, aes(x=Schedule, fill=Schedule))+
  geom_bar(stat="count")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = wrap_format(10))+
  ylab("Number of respondents")

d <- ggplot(data=Data, aes(x=Region, fill=Region))+
  geom_bar(stat="count")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = wrap_format(10))+
  ylab("Number of respondents")

plot_grid(a,b,c,d)
```

This presents the plots in a nice grid. However the graphs are unreadably small unless one zooms in a lot.

However, messing with the fig.height and fig.width either make the graphs incredibly tiny or larger but then all the data in each graph is so squashed.

How can one simply resize the graph appropriately while maintaining readability?

Comment: Do you have to use 20/40 (height/width)? Can you use 5/7 or 5/10? Both of those look pretty good to me and maintains readability.

Comment: Unfortunately that makes the graphs unreadable squashed

Comment: Ok. I can't reproduce your results. Do you have some settings in `knitr::opts_chunk$set()` which might affect it? Like `fig.asp`, `out.width` or `out.heigh`?